# Sparql query does not return uri/object

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, endpoint, dbpedia

So, im doing a simple query. I want all uri/property/object of a certain dbpedia uri, ex: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer. The problem is, it returns just the property of it, as we can see on the resultset.

**Class:**

```
public class SemanticCrawlerImpl implements SemanticCrawler {   
    public void search(Model graph, String resourceURI) {
        graph.read(resourceURI);

        // Create a new query
        String queryString = 
            "SELECT ?url ?property ?object" +
            "WHERE {" +
            "      <"+resourceURI+"> ?property ?object ." + 
            "}";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        System.out.println("----------------------");

        System.out.println("Query Result Sheet");

        System.out.println("----------------------");

        // Execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, graph);
        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();

        // Output query results    
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

        qe.close();
    }
}
```

**Resultset**

```
| url | property                                                  | objectWHERE |
=================================================================================
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/property/medaltemplatesTitle>         |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail>                   |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/property/name>                        |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/property/daviscupresult>              |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>         |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>         |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/property/hopmancupresult>             |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink>        |             |
|     | <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject>                        |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>         |             |
|     | <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject>                        |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>         |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/height>                      |             |
|     | <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject>                        |             |
|     | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>                    |             |
|     | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthYear>                   |             |
```

Comment: The string concatenation `?object" + "WHERE` gives you `select ?objectWHERE`, and you don't use a variable `?objectWHERE`.  The `where` in queries is optional (i.e., you can write `select ?a ?b { ... }`, which would avoid the problem.  But you really should be using newlines in the query string anyway, so that you get better syntax error messages for line numbers.  Also, string concatenation like `<"+resourceURI+">` is error prone;  you should use a ParameterizedSparqlString instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your query, a missing space. Note that the output should be "object", not "objectWHERE". Also, there is no need for your ?url variable, since you are not using it in your query. Replace this fragment in your code and it will work:

```
 // Create a new query
        String queryString = 
            "SELECT ?property ?object " +
            "WHERE {" +
            "      <"+resourceURI+"> ?property ?object ." + 
            "}";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
```

Also, I don't get why you first read the resource locally and then issue the sparql query against the local graph. Why not doing it directly against the dbpedia endpoint?
Something like this:

```
String resourceURI = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer";
String queryString = 
            "SELECT ?property ?object " +
            "WHERE {" +
            "      <"+resourceURI+"> ?property ?object ." + 
            "}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
//System.out.println(queryIn);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect(); 
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
qe.close();
```

I think it is cleaner.

Comment: Awesome! Then how could I query again on a given resultset? Like doing a query like: <URI> owl:sameAs <Object> . 
              <Subject> owl:sameAs <URI> .

Comment: If you want to query for a variable on the result set, you have to do something like `while (results.hasNext()){
            QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
            Resource variable = qs.getResource("?object");            
        }`

Comment: If you want to do a query like the one you mentioned in your comment, you just have to change your sparql query to something like `select ?sameAs where{{<yourResourceURIgoeshere> owl:sameAs ?sameAs.} UNION{?sameAs owl:sameAs <yourResourceURIgoeshere>}}` (if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: This answer has come up before, and the question is a duplicate.